# What's a negative word for "subtle"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

I'm trying to describe software bugs that are hard to track down due to the mistake (introduced by the developer) being a very subtle one.

"when these errors manifest they do so in a ...(pernicious?)... way"

It's on the tip-of-my-tongue and is a word most people have heard of (so it can be used in marketing material without a fear the reader will need to lookup the word).

Comment: Insidious ?  : *Working or spreading harmfully in a subtle or stealthy manner:* insidious rumors; an insidious disease.

Comment: A well-known simile, laden with irony, is the term *as subtle as a sledgehammer* - which implies that the thing in question is anything but subtle.

Comment: Since the context is one of "subtle" manifestation of **errors**, it's pretty obvious there are negative connotations (though to my mind, "subtle" itself is a neutral term). But the problem is most negative adverbial usages of "subtly" (or synonyms) involve additional anthropomorphization (i.e. ***slyly*** implies ***deliberately*** being subtle). It therefore makes a difference whether OP wants to characterize the behaviour of his errors as ***intentionally*** trying to avoid detection, or simply that they're difficult to identify because they're not easily noticed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers great comment - it's the latter I'm interested in. "difficult to identify because they're not easily noticed"

Comment: haha I thought it probably would be! That kinda rules out several suggestions here. Your best bet might be [**inconspicuous**](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/inconspicuous) or synonyms, and forget about the "negative associations", since they're already implicit in the overall context.

Comment: "Pernicious" actually sounds ok to me. It's basically a synonym of insidious.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers here. There's nothing particularly malicious about incorrectly software behavior that's not easily spotted (It's a computer program with mistakes in it; there's no hint of malice.), so "subtle" works better in a technical context than the more flowery options presented.

Comment: @jpmc26: Yes, although OP himself already used the figuratively "living" term ***bug***. So it would have been at least *possible*, until the later clarification (in a comment, though it really should be edited into the question text itself) for answers to take that a bit further in the "anthropomorphism" direction (with words like ***sneaky, sly, furtive***).

Comment: A lot of the answers here include a measure of how bad the effect or 'intent' of the bug is rather than just it's difficulty to track/detect. Of the answers, Hidden, Elusive or Obscure are probably best at not colouring visibility with outcome.

Comment: we are talking about programming here, so while it's not the word you're looking for, the word Big is fine!  And using more the one word can sometimes be a  good idea.  I suppose you could say a vicious bug!

Comment: **Tricksy** "Them's some tricksy bugs I been battling this past tenday."

Comment: @WayfaringStranger That's one for the *English Frobnication & Abuse* proposal.

Comment: Both a "subtle bug" and a bug bug "manifesting in a subtle way" are pretty common idioms.

Comment: I would consider some reference to a small, distasteful animal -- weasel, snake, rat, cockroach, etc.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**[Insidious](https://www.google.com/search?q=insidious%20definition)** is probably your best bet,

> adjective
>  proceeding in a gradual, subtle way, but with very
>   harmful effects.

(Google)

but you might also consider **[treacherous](https://www.google.com/search?q=treacherous%20definition)**, which has the same connotation of remaining hidden and doing damage unexpectedly:

> adjective
>  1. guilty of or involving betrayal or deception.
>  2.
>   (of ground, water, conditions, etc.) presenting hidden or unpredictable dangers.

(Google)

Comment: It would probably be helpful for you to include a definition for those words as well as citing the source.

Comment: from Google:  insidious:  proceeding in a gradual, subtle way, but with harmful effects.

Comment: As a software developer, I use the word insidious for this exact situation.

Comment: Excellent. I just learned the usage of the word of the movie title. (y)

Comment: Pretty sure you only want to use "treacherous" in cases of actual sabotage.

Comment: @MarchHo I agree unless the use was to describe the software as a whole (*"These insidious bugs have made the software treacherous"*) in which case the second definition would apply.

Comment: I think *gradual* seems strange, when discussing software bugs in an objective context.  It only makes sense if there is some kind of version control and the bugs are making the software progressively worse.

Comment: @AlexW I agree that it would be unusual and not appropriate in all cases. However, if there was a bug that was causing data to gradually become corrupted (for example, every time a record is edited it would reset some values to defaults) then insidious could be a very apt description.

Comment: Insidious is quite emotive and would need to be in the right context, treacherous even more so. For software I wouldn't want to put this in client release notes for example. (Software dev and native English speaker)

Comment: I'm not sure I would recommend `insidious`, at least not in the same context the OP mentioned. While `insidious` does mean "subtle and harmful" it also implies that these effects build up gradually, over time. To me it's a `creepy` word, both the word itself and its effect.

Answer (score 54):

**[Elusive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/elusive)**

> adjective
>  difficult to find, catch, or achieve.

(oxforddictionaries.com)

Or, more fun and more negative:

**[Sneaky](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sneaky)**

> adjective
>   1. furtive; sly.

(oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: +1 Actually 'sneaky' works well when talking about software bugs :-)

Answer (score 17):

**Obscure** is a possibility

> hard to perceive
>
> not readily seen
>
> inconspicuous or unnoticeable

However, this would work better if it's a bug that's difficult to reproduce, rather than a bug which is difficult to find the cause of.

Ref: [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obscure?s=t)

Answer (score 5):

**pernicious**

One adjective that comes to mind is " pernicious ".

Pernicious :   having a harmful effect, especially in a harmful or subtle way.

Comment: *Pernicious* is in the question. Perhaps that's why it came to your mind...

Answer (score 3):

## Perfidious

Surprised no one has mentioned [perfidious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perfidious).

**adjective**
1. deliberately faithless; treacherous; deceitful:
*a perfidious lover.*

Treachery implies subtlety.

Comment: Sneaky was first suggested by Avon http://english.stackexchange.com/a/261306/44619

Comment: Sorry, I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you answered your own question - pernicious is a great word for that.

Elusive doesn't really ring negative, nor does sneaky without more context.  Insidious and treacherous are definitely both negative, but I'm not sure I'd want to describe even the worst bugs as either (at least not in front of stakeholders).

There are plenty, though: ruinous, nefarious (a personal favorite), deleterious.

Comment: Hrm... *pernicious* has a connotation to me of being persistent and hard to resolve despite repeated efforts, though. Not quite what OP is describing.

Comment: _Sneaky_ is not negative without more context?! It's very much inherently negative to me. I can't even think of any contexts where it wouldn't be negative.

Comment: Talking about kids or pets, it's almost alway light-hearted.  Or if someone is sneaky and organizes a surprise birthday party.  I don't know, there are probably quite a few ways it isn't negative.

Answer (score 2):

***indiscernible*** or ***undetectable*** - in the context you're looking for.

***'under the radar'*** (not a single word) or ***stealth(ily)***

*elusive*, *insidious*

Answer (score 1):

**Devious** ([www.dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/devious))

adjective

1. departing from the most direct way; circuitous; indirect: a devious course.
2. without definite course; vagrant: a devious current.
3. departing from the proper or accepted way; roundabout: a devious procedure.
4. not straightforward; shifty or crooked: a devious scheme to acquire wealth.

Answer (score 0):

*Sly* could be used. Here's the first [definition of *sly*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sly) in Oxford Dictionaries Online:

> **sly**
>
> adjective
>
> > 1  Having or showing a cunning and deceitful nature

Comment: **“Google” is *not* a citable reference!**

Comment: Hi, Thomas Molloy. I added a link to the source online dictionary for your quotation and identified it in your answer, and I removed the attribution to "Google," which (as tchrist emphatically points out) is not a citable reference. I think you'll find that identifying and including links to your reference sources will make your answers stronger and hence more popular with upvoters.

Answer (score 0):

**surreptitious**

adj.
Obtained, done, or made by clandestine or stealthy means.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/surreptitious

Answer (score -2):

I suggest *lurkingly*. Here are the first three [definitions of *lurk*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lurker) from Dictionary.com:

> 1. to lie or wait in concealment, as a person in ambush; remain in or around a place secretly or furtively.
> 2. to go furtively; slink; steal.
> 3. to exist unperceived or unsuspected.

Comment: Is 'lurkingly' really a word? Is there a reference you can point to?

Comment: Why not? Lurking is a valid word. Just make an adverb out of it. I am not too uptight or by-the-dictionary about these things.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lurk?s=t

Comment: @ArtforLife When quoting, please indicate the source; otherwise, by policy, they may be deleted as copyright violations.

Comment: I added a link to the source of the definitions in your answer, but I think that the answer still has a bit of a problem in that it presents an adverb (_lurkingly_) as the suggested darker version of an adjective (_subtle_). Perhaps you would do better with _lurking_ as your suggestion? (I think it might be a pretty good match for what the poster is seeking, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the tips. It is up to the writer to choose "proper" words that he thinks relay his meaning best. I just suggested this as an option.