# Word identification

Tags: meaning, synonyms

There is a word and its meaning is to cause harm in a slow way over time, that is something that creeps up on you and may even be subtle (or at least the definition is something like this I can't remember exactly).

I can't remember the word but it is bugging me and I will recognise it immediately.

Google returned nothing useful to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should include some of the results you consider not useful. This will prevent users here doing duplicate work. Show your research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a negative word for "subtle"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261302/whats-a-negative-word-for-subtle) where 'insidious' is the top answer.

Comment: Perhaps a synonym of erode works: *Main Entry: erode Part of Speech: verb Definition: deteriorate; wear away Synonyms: abrade, bite, consume, corrode, crumble, destroy, disintegrate, eat, gnaw, grind down, scour, spoil, waste, wear down*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**insidious**?

1.
stealthy, subtle, cunning, or treacherous

2.
**working in a subtle or apparently innocuous way**, but nevertheless deadly: an insidious illness